# Ativar/desativar um ActionButton em determinada página

Tags: javascript, firefox

Estou desenvolvendo uma extensão para navegadores Firefox, logo surgiu a necessidade de controlar o botão de ação de forma que ele fique inativo até que o usuário entre em determinada página.

Exemplificando, vou utilizar como exemplo a página "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/".
Pois bem, gostaria que o botão ficasse ativo somente quando estivesse com a aba ativa e com essa página aberta.

Segue o meu código:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

// o painel que será exibido
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: data.url("painel.html")
});


// as configurações do botão de ação
var actionBtn = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
    id: "ID do botão",
    label: "Descrição do botão",
    icon: {
        "16": "./logo-16.png",
        "36": "./logo-36.png"
    },
    onClick : openPanel
});

// função que exibe o painel quando o botão de ação é clicado.
function openPanel(){
    panel.show();
}
```

Até o momento tenho o código normal, somente para abrir o painel quando o usuário clicar nele. Como posso fazer esse controle de ativar/desativar?

Comment: Você pode desabilitar um botão setando a propriedade disabled para true

Comment: sim, isto eu vi na documentação. Mas a questão é: como fazer para ele ficar desativado nas demais páginas que não interessa a minha extensão? Quero que o botão fique ativo somente em uma URL especifica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique o valor da URL, **tabs.activeTab.url**, e caso seja o que você quer, você pode desabilitar o botão setando a propriedade disabled para true;

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

function onOpen(tab) {
  console.log(tab.url + " is open");
  tab.on("pageshow", logShow);
  tab.on("activate", logActivate);    // Voce pode acessar a aba atual nesta funcao
  tab.on("deactivate", logDeactivate);
  tab.on("close", logClose);
}

function logShow(tab) {
  console.log(tab.url + " is loaded");
}

function logActivate(tab) {
  if(tab.url=="http://www.google.com"){
      actionBtn.disabled = true;
  } else {
      actionBtn.disabled = false;
  }
  console.log(tab.url + " is activated");
}

function logDeactivate(tab) {
  console.log(tab.url + " is deactivated");
}

function logClose(tab) {
  console.log(tab.url + " is closed");
}

tabs.on('open', onOpen);
```

Referências:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582607/find-url-of-current-tab-making-a-firefox-browser-add-on

Comment: Perfeito! Já vou marcar como resolvida, mas antes... uma dúvida: Se o usuário já estiver na página que eu determinei o botão não será ativado, ele precisará alterar para outra guia e voltar para tornar botão torne-se acessível. Há alguma forma de fazer isto (ativar o botão) com o usuário estando com a guia aberta na url especifica?

Comment: O evento Activate é quem fará isto acontecer, ao ativar a guia, ele verifica a URL e ativa (ou não) o botão de acordo.

Comment: Sim, mas se eu estiver em uma guia abrindo aquela página definida, quando terminar o carregamento o botão não ficará ativo. Eu teria que alternar as guias e voltar para a anterior para que o evento 'active' funcione...

Comment: Se o active não funcionar neste caso, e os outros eventos também não detectarem isto, talvez você poderia adicionalmente acrescentar um timer com intervalo de 300ms que verifique a url da aba atual.

Comment: vou tentar isto, obrigado.